# python automated mailing doesn't work properly

Tags: android, email, automation, smtplib

I made a Python code that automatically sends mail.

The contents of the body in the mail were written in HTML format so that the mail could go at a specific time.

If you send an e-mail in the form of Text, the e-mail linked to Samsung e-mail (email service on Android phone) does not show the body. (When checked by Android phone, the attachment is sent normally, but the body is exposed in white.)

Conversely, when sending mail in the form of Html, the contents of the body are printed twice only in the groupware mail (PC).

(If you send it to the groupware mail, Naver mail, Daum mail, or Google mail registered in Samsung email, it will only be printed once.)

I don't understand at all the phenomena that are printed twice only in "Groupware PC" and that the text does not come out when printed in text form in Samsung e-mail, so what part should I check?

Comment: Where is the code? Screenshots? Maybe it is a settings problem in that mail-client showing the text twice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70573944/when-sending-python-automated-mail-add-an-attachment-and-print-the-body-content